# Determine whether this series converges or not.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to determinate if the following series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
I see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan{\frac{1}{n}}$ obviously diverges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\frac{1}{n}$ but still can't figure how to use the comparison test for the series above.

Comment: $\sin x > x/2$ for small positive $x.$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\sin y\geq \frac{2}{\pi}y$$
for $0\leq y\leq \pi/2$ (by concavity) and
$$\tan x\geq x$$
for $0\leq x< \pi/2$. Combining these, we get
$$\sin\tan x\geq \frac{2}{\pi} x$$
for $0\leq x\leq \arctan(\pi/2)\simeq 1.00388$. In particular,

> $$\sin \tan\frac{1}{n}\geq\frac{2}{n\pi}\quad\text{for all }n\geq 1$$

and hence the series diverges by the comparison test

Answer (score 0):

Using $\sin \epsilon \sim \epsilon$ ant $\tan \epsilon \sim \epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ and the quotient comparison test:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{\sin{\tan{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{{\tan{\dfrac{1}{n}}}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=1\ne 0$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{\tan{\dfrac{1}{n}}}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{\dfrac{1}{n}}}\text{ (divergent).}$$

Answer (score 0):

As this is a series with positive terms, you  can use *equivalence*: $ \sin u\sim_0 u$, so the series $\sin\tan\dfrac1n\sim_\infty\tan \dfrac1n$, and equivalentseries with positive terms both converge or both diverge.

Comment: Why should we use sin(x) -> x. I mean as n tends to infinity its obvious x tends to 0 and hence we can use it. But it wouldn't be good for previous terms when n is small. I am having this difficulty in getting the fact that when the nth term converges to something , the series converges. Because I think the previous terms should also affect. I hope I have explained my doubt properly. It has been a confusion for weeks now.

Comment: I didn't say $\sin x$ tend to $x$ –  which is meaninglesss. I said it was *equivalent near* $0$, which has a very precise meaning in *Asymptotic analysis*. This allows to use the criterion of convergence /divergence for equivalent series.

Comment: ok , thanks , got it !

Answer (score 0):

The unction $f(x)=\sin{\tan{\dfrac{1}{x}}}$ is continuous, positive and decreasing in $[1,\infty)$, with **integral test** we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{\tan{\frac{1}{n}}}=\int_1^\infty\sin{\tan{\frac{1}{x}}}dx=\int_1^0\sin{\tan{u}}\frac{-1}{u^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\sin{\tan{u}}}{u^2}dx\geq\int_0^1\frac{1}{2u}dx=\infty$$